# Howto unseal vault server, running in a docker container

Tags: configuration, docker, consul

I have a docker compose setup that successfully starts consul (config [here](http://pastebin.com/NWQHsdWg)). Vault seems to start ok, except for some errors around setting the TTL (logs [here](http://pastebin.com/kbVnrYxR)).

Further on, consul seems to be hiccuping when trying to reach `/v1/agent/check/fail/vault:127.0.0.1:8200:vault-sealed-check?note=Vault+Sealed`. Apparently `'vault:127.0.0.1:8200:vault-sealed-check' status is now critical`.

```
consul1    |     2016/11/05 20:50:04 [DEBUG] agent: Check 'vault:127.0.0.1:8200:vault-sealed-check' status is now critical
consul1    |     2016/11/05 20:50:04 [DEBUG] agent: Service 'vault:127.0.0.1:8200' in sync
consul1    |     2016/11/05 20:50:04 [DEBUG] agent: Service 'consul' in sync
consul1    |     2016/11/05 20:50:04 [DEBUG] agent: Check 'vault:127.0.0.1:8200:vault-sealed-check' in sync
consul1    |     2016/11/05 20:50:04 [DEBUG] agent: Node info in sync
consul1    |     2016/11/05 20:50:04 [DEBUG] http: Request PUT /v1/agent/check/fail/vault:127.0.0.1:8200:vault-sealed-check?note=Vault+Sealed (92.314µs) from=172.18.0.3:48742
```

When vault container starts (with consul backend) **1)** how do we get the initial ***i)*** key and ***ii)*** root token. I'm using Hashicorp's official [vault image](https://hub.docker.com/_/vault/) with my custom **/vault/config/vault.hcl** (and [consul image](https://hub.docker.com/_/consul/)).

Ultimately, I want to know **2)** how to unseal a vault server. And in this case, I want to unseal the vault server, that's running in the docker container. And **3)** is this all I need, to start writing secrets to vault.

Comment: `vault --help` is a good starting point.

Comment: @FlorinAsăvoaie Yes **1)** `vault unseal` and `vault unseal` are available at the vault command-line. And **2)** running within the docker container, should will out the initial key and token. But I can't see those values from outside the container.

Comment: Run the container for the first time in attached mode?

Comment: You can unseal Vault using different KMS services (or Kubernetes) with our Vault Kubernetes operator https://banzaicloud.com/blog/vault-unsealing/

Answer (score 2):

In order to unseal a vault-in-a-container using [official source vault image](https://hub.docker.com/_/vault/) I would initiate the vault container with:

```
vm# docker run -it --cap-add IPC_LOCK -p 8200:8200 -p 8215:8125 --name vault --volume /my/vault:/my/vault vault server -config=/my/vault/vaultCfg.hcl
```

where the vm is running 1.12.4 docker engine and the vault hcl config lists:

```
backend "consul" {
  address = "myconsul.com:8500"
  path = "vault"
}

listener "tcp" {
  address = "0.0.0.0:8200"
  tls_disable = 1
}
```

and then on the same docker host:

```
vm# VAULT_ADDR=http://myvault.com:8200 
vm# docker exec -it vault vault  "$@" init -address=${VAULT_ADDR}
```

And expect output like:

```
2016/12/11 10:21:10.628736 [WARN ] physical/consul: appending trailing forward slash to path
2016/12/11 12:09:12.117238 [INFO ] core: security barrier not initialized
2016/12/11 12:09:12.136037 [INFO ] core: security barrier initialized: shares=5 threshold=3
2016/12/11 12:09:12.169987 [INFO ] core: post-unseal setup starting
2016/12/11 12:09:12.181963 [INFO ] core: successfully mounted backend: type=generic path=secret/
2016/12/11 12:09:12.181990 [INFO ] core: successfully mounted backend: type=cubbyhole path=cubbyhole/
2016/12/11 12:09:12.182057 [INFO ] core: successfully mounted backend: type=system path=sys/
2016/12/11 12:09:12.182156 [INFO ] rollback: starting rollback manager
2016/12/11 12:09:12.218527 [INFO ] core: post-unseal setup complete
2016/12/11 12:09:12.218733 [INFO ] core/startClusterListener: starting listener
2016/12/11 12:09:12.218899 [INFO ] core/startClusterListener: serving cluster requests: cluster_listen_address=[::]:8201
2016/12/11 12:09:12.228888 [INFO ] core: root token generated
2016/12/11 12:09:12.228905 [INFO ] core: pre-seal teardown starting
2016/12/11 12:09:12.228911 [INFO ] core/stopClusterListener: stopping listeners
2016/12/11 12:09:12.228921 [INFO ] core/startClusterListener: shutting down listeners
2016/12/11 12:09:12.724179 [INFO ] core/startClusterListener: listeners successfully shut down
2016/12/11 12:09:12.724209 [INFO ] core/stopClusterListener: success
2016/12/11 12:09:12.724225 [INFO ] rollback: stopping rollback manager
2016/12/11 12:09:12.724250 [INFO ] core: pre-seal teardown complete
```

This [link](https://www.katacoda.com/courses/docker-production/vault-secrets) may help.  Requires working Internet connection for `docker run`

Answer (score 0):

So I found a working solution. A working setup with ***i.*** a consul node, ***ii.*** a vault instance talking to it then ***iii.*** the ability to connect to vault, and generate initial unseal and root tokens.

***A)*** With this [dockerfile](https://github.com/twashing/gently/blob/master/docker-compose.yml#L17-L41), I can ***i.*** `docker-compose build && docker-compose up`.

***B)*** Then in another shell, I can connect with a `$ docker exec -i -t gently_vault_1 /bin/sh`.

***C)*** And then, in that shell, simply run `vault init`.

```
/ # vault init
Unseal Key 1: asdf...
Unseal Key 2: qwer...
Unseal Key 3: zxcv...
Unseal Key 4: piou...
Unseal Key 5: lkjh...
Initial Root Token: mbnv...

Vault initialized with 5 keys and a key threshold of 3. Please
securely distribute the above keys. When the Vault is re-sealed,
restarted, or stopped, you must provide at least 3 of these keys
to unseal it again.

Vault does not store the master key. Without at least 3 keys,
your Vault will remain permanently sealed.
```

Comment: I would avoid using someone else's own-rolled apparently secure vault image, irrespective of how [hagiographically](http://www.interruptsoftware.com) other people describe them.  Unless you've verified their src.  Or they're Ken Thompson or Dennis Ritchie.

Comment: Dockerfile is no longer available. Consider pasting it in a response here.